# Issue with running DJI UX SDK 4.7

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Trying to run DJI UX SDK 4.7 Android sample application and it crashes every time I try going into the Complete Demo of UI Widgets. It appears when the *Helper.install(MApplication.this);* is called that it is looking for a field called *pathList* on *dalvik.system.PathClassLoader* that is not found. Even though I set a breakpoint and I can see it clearly defined on the object.

With more debugging I found this message in the LogCat:

*08-25 06:19:38.785 6735-6735/net.skyora.overwatch A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x21 in tid 6735 (kyora.overwatch)*

I will fully admit Android development is new to me and this maybe a newbie mistake I am doing.  Can anyone shed some light on what is going on?

***UPDATE:***
So I got the app to work with the Android ARM emulator, it seems to be an issue with the Android X86 emulators. I am running X86 No Google APIs API 22. The compile and target SDK are 24. The min SDK is 19.

Some things I discovered

First, I was able to revert to UX SDK 4.6 without an issue.

Second, I went back to 4.7 and I started to disable widgets in the main UI. I found a majority like the MapWidget, camera widgets, FlightModeWidget all stopped the application.  However, the FPVWidget, FPVOverlayWidget, PreFlightStatusWidget and a few others did not create this error.

Another odd bit of behavior, is that the 4.6 UX SDK sample app for Android would prompt me to login into my DJI account but the 4.7 UX SDK does not. Is this by design?

Comment: I suggest try registering a new app on DJI developer site and recreate the new app.

Comment: I recreated a new app and it did not work

Comment: I'm so glad to see the DJI developers paying attention to the stack exchange

Answer (score 3):

@Keenan Newton - for a faster response from DJI Developer Support please email us directly at dev@dji.com.  We can troubleshoot issues there and update posts with the outcome.

However for your issue you may want to check out [DJI's Release Notes](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/downloads/)  It says "On x86 devices that run Android API 23 or above, if the application is targeted with API 23 or above, FFmpeg lib might lead to runtime crashes or warnings.".

You are using x86 device (emulator), with target 24 and so use target 22 or below.

Comment: last time I tried your developer email, I got a quick response first time, however, after that I never got any response for a few weeks.I dont think yo uhave enough resources to help everyone.